# Extract the first 2 directories in a path

Tags: variable

I need to extract the first 2 directories in a path that is in the variable $ORACLE_HOME

```
ORACLE_HOME=/oradba/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/testdb
```

I need the value: `/oradba/app/`

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

1. Using cut (tacking on the final `/`):

   ```
   ORACLE_HOME=$(printf "%s" "$ORACLE_HOME" | cut -d/ -f1-3)/
   ```
2. Using parameter expansion twice; the first strips away the first two elements of the directory, then the second strips that remainder away from the original variable:

   ```
   suffix=${ORACLE_HOME#/*/*/}
   ORACLE_HOME=${ORACLE_HOME%"$suffix"}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives.  The latter is more convoluted, but safer as it doesn't require you to know how many directories are in the variable:

```
$ echo ${ORACLE_HOME%/*/*/*/*}/
/oradba/app/
$ echo $ORACLE_HOME | awk -F/ 'BEGIN {OFS="/"} {print $1,$2,$3,""}'
/oradba/app/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo $ORACLE_HOME | cut -d/ -f-3
```

For example:

```
$ ORACLE_HOME=/oradba/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/testdb
$ echo $ORACLE_HOME | cut -d/ -f-3
/oradba/app
$
```